# Oracle Wallet : Facebook Non valid certificate

Tags: oracle, facebook, ssl, https

I'm trying to add facebook certificate to Oracle Wallet using **orapki**

```
orapki wallet add -wallet [path] -trusted_cert -cert c:\-facebookcom.crt
```

The certificate was downloaded using Firefox.

but I get the error : PKI-04001 : Non valid certificate.

Does anyone have an idea please ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle wallet manager doesn't support wildcard cert.

Normal certs look like `s1.feacbook.com` .. `s2.facebook.com` etc. 
For each server `s1,s2..,sN` you need the separate certificate. Wildcard cert allows replacing all these certs with one  `*.facebook.com`

[wildcard-compatibility](https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/wildcard-compatibility.htm)